# how to replace double quotes and nan with null in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a txt file via pandas. Trying to replace quotes (") with (null), but no luck. Also getting nan values, which is not needed. How to resolve this ?

**code**:

```
import pandas as pd 
df1 = pd.read_csv("file.txt", sep = '\t')
df1['location'] = df1['location'].astype(str)   
df1['location'] = df1['location'].replace('"', '')
```

input:
[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHygL.png)

output of code: [current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doBZk.png)

expected output: [expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLz4Q.png)

Comment: have you tried `df1['location'].replace('"', '', regex=True)`?

Comment: What is the motivation for making valid json invalid? Are you maybe looking to instead parse it into a dictionary?

Comment: @anthino12 : Thanks , ```regex = True``` worked, how to replace the nan with null ?